# How to cast object to type in C#

Tags: c#, types, casting

I need to cast object to one of types that have specific property and method.
First, I need to check if my object is an instance of one of this types and then I need to cast it to this type and perform some actions.

How can I do it without code repeating?

```
var foo = GetAnimalById(animalId); // Animal type returned to foo

var animal = new Animal(); // Animal class hasn't Age property and GiveVitamins method
if (foo is Tiger) { 
    animal = foo as Tiger; 
    if (animal.Age >= 10)
    {
        animal.GiveVitamins();
    }
}
if (foo is Lion) { 
    animal = foo as Lion; 
    if (animal.Age >= 10)
    {
        animal.GiveVitamins();
    }
}
if (foo is Monkey) { 
    animal = foo as Monkey; 
    if (animal.Age >= 10)
    {
        animal.GiveVitamins();
    }
}
```

Comment: There is a dynamic dispatch example using `dynamic`, but I'll leave that for now. It looks like all the animals might share the `Age` and `GiveVitamins` members, so why not promote those to the base `Animal` class?

Comment: I think there is something wrong with the design here. Why isn't the `Age` property in the `Animal` class? Can you name an animal that does not get old?

Comment: If you can't move `Age` and `GiveVitamines` to `Animal` consider to create an interface that contains both, let `Tiger`, `Lion` and `Monkey` implement that interface and check for that implementation.

Comment: None of your casts makes sense. You access `Age` and call `GiveVitamines()` everytime on a variable of type `Animal`. So why don't you just use `foo.Age` and `foo.GiveVitamines()` if `foo` is already an `Animal`, too? And why do you assing a `new Animal()` first that you don't need?

Comment: Another remark: you do type checking twice, first with `is` and then with `as`. The usual way is: `animal = foo as Lion; if (animal != null) {...}`

Comment: This is just a simplified production code, and unfortunately it's designed not to have Age property in the parent Animal class. And I'm not allowed to change it :(

Comment: You better describe your conditions BEFORE any answers were given.

Comment: even if it's simplified it should exactly show what your problem is. From the code shown, it's not clear (at least for me), because this code only compiles if `Age` and `GiveVitamines()` _are_ members of `Animal`, so there would be no problem at all. And I don't want to suggest solutions based on guesses about what exactly you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there is something wrong with your design. Every animal should have an age, so instead of having a separate `Age` property in `Tiger`, `Lion` and `Monkey`, move the `Age` property to the `Animal` class.

Another strange thing about your design is that the animals don't give vitamins. They receive vitamins. I think you should rename the method to `ReceiveVitamins`. Then, create an interface like this:

```
interface VitaminReceivable {
   void ReceiveVitamins();
}
```

Have `Tiger`, `Lion` and `Monkey` all implement this interface, then you can just do:

```
var foo = GetAnimalById(animalId); // Animal type returned to foo

var animal = new Animal(); // Animal class hasn't Age property and GiveVitamins method
if (foo is VitaminReceivable) { 
    animal = foo; 
    if (animal.Age >= 10)
    {
        ((VitaminReceivable)animal).ReceiveVitamins();
    }
}
```

EDIT:

Now that I know you can't have `Age` in `Animal`, you should create another interface:

```
interface Ageable {
    int Age { get; }
}
```

Have the subclasses implement the interface and then you can write this:

```
var foo = GetAnimalById(animalId); // Animal type returned to foo

var animal = new Animal(); // Animal class hasn't Age property and GiveVitamins method
if (foo is VitaminReceivable && foo is Ageable) { 
    animal = foo; 
    if (((Ageable)animal).Age >= 10)
    {
        ((VitaminReceivable)animal).ReceiveVitamins();
    }
}
```

Comment: Your casting is horrible. Use 'as' and be more powerful.

Comment: @eocron What other solutions are there? I can't think of any.

Comment: Animals give vitamins when they are eaten, assuming that Animal.IsTasty is set to true.

Comment: @eocron What do you mean by being more powerful when casting using 'as' ? Can you please elaborate on why casting with 'as' is more powerful?

Comment: @eocron I don't quite understand what is the advantage of using `as` here. As far as I know, using `as` produces `null` if the conversion fails, while casting throws an exception straight away. But what's the difference in this case? I checked if the types are compatible with `Ageable` and `VitaminReceivable` in advance.